# Difference between report and sub-report

Tags: vb.net

What is a sub report and how is it different from a report?
Thanks
Furqan

Comment: Some context would help. Crystal reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Subreport** in Crystal Reports means a Report within a Report . When we want to show some additional information about the data in the Crystal Reports , we use the subreports to show the details. Subreports we show within the main Crystal Reports and also we can show it as On-Demand report , that means we put an Hyper link in the row, and when user click that hyper link then will get the subreport